# Rounded avatar ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rounded-corners

I would like to have my avatars that my users upload to be round on my rails app project for Udemy. The image still comes out square the way it was uploaded.

below is my show.html.erb file

---

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
 <div class="avatar"><%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url %></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h1><%= @user.profile.first_name %> <%= @user.profile.last_name %></h1>
  <h3><span class="job_title_icon"><%= job_title_icon %></span> <%= @user.profile.job_title %></h3>
  <div class="well profile-block profile-description">
   <h3>Background</h3>   
   <%= @user.profile.description %>
  </div>

  <% if current_user.plan_id == 2 %>
  <div class="well profile-block contact-info">
    <h3>Contact:</h3>  
    <%= @user.profile.phone_number %><br/>
    <%= @user.profile.contact_email %><br/>
  </div> 
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Below is my users,css.scss file

---

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
 <div class="avatar"><%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url %></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h1><%= @user.profile.first_name %> <%= @user.profile.last_name %></h1>
  <h3><span class="job_title_icon"><%= job_title_icon %></span> <%= @user.profile.job_title %></h3>
  <div class="well profile-block profile-description">
   <h3>Background</h3>   
   <%= @user.profile.description %>
  </div>

  <% if current_user.plan_id == 2 %>
  <div class="well profile-block contact-info">
    <h3>Contact:</h3>  
    <%= @user.profile.phone_number %><br/>
    <%= @user.profile.contact_email %><br/>
  </div> 
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you re-upload your CSS? it seems you only have the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you might be using Twitter Bootstrap. If so, there is a handy CSS class built in.

Just add `class: 'img-circle'` to your image_tag

```
...
#change this line as follows
<div class="avatar"><%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'img-circle' %></div>
...
```

[This page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-shapes) of the Bootstrap docs has lots of useful info and examples.

Comment: thank you Im such a newby though what would adding it look like

Answer (score 3):

I think setting your `avatar` class so that the image is round is a better way to approach it.

In your CSS, you define it as such:

```
.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  // also might be good to set width and height
}
```