# How to mask an image with Active Storage and mini_magick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mask, minimagick, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to create an avatar that is circular instead of a rectangle.

The rails code below successfully resizes and crops the image. I'm using Active Storage to upload the file. However I'm struggling to apply a mask to it.

I was trying to composite and use the mini_magick_clip gem, but neither works. Maybe it's just a syntax error, but I couldn't find any examples on the web.

Do you have suggestions on how best to achieve such a circular avatar?

```html
# app/models/comment.rb

class Signature < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  require "mini_magick"
  # require "mini_magick_clip"

  def avatar
    mask = MiniMagick::Image.open "public/mask.png"
    upload = self.image
    avatar = upload.variant(
      combine_options: {
        resize: "160x160^",
        gravity: "center",
        extent: "160x160",
        # mask: mask,
      }
    ).processed

  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest storing and serving your avatars in their original shape. It's easy to make them look circular (or whatever shape you want) using CSS. You can find [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950153/6376149) and [an example here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_rounded_images.asp).

Comment: Thank you! But it's not a good solution, because I want to use these images in email signatures, and some email applications do not support advanced CSS. It has to be as basic as possible for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Well, in that case CSS really isn't the right solution.